# Web scraping an interactive chart for time series data *newbie*

Tags: python

Could someone please advise/assist me on how I can download the data behind the interactive chart?

[image]

Many thanks! Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting data out of svg plots is not that straight forward.
I would recommend extracting the raw data.

This can be done e.g. by using directly their API:

Endpoints are:

```
# Live:
    https://air.plumelabs.com/api/v1/live/7vZ5/
# Week:
    https://air.plumelabs.com/api/v1/week/7vZ5/
# Month:
    https://air.plumelabs.com/api/v1/month/7vZ5/
# Year:
    https://air.plumelabs.com/api/v1/month/7vZ5/
```

Alternativly you can make use of Selenium and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: This looks promising: https://api.midway.tomtom.com/ranking/live/ESP%2FCircle%2Fmadrid

Comment: You need to convert the json. Maybe there are some tools available for this. Normally it is quite easy - got to the website with e.g. chrome - right click and select developer tools. Then there is a network tab available - here you can filter for XHR requests. Now you should be a able to see all api calls from the website (if it is a client side rendered application). For more information e.g.: https://egghead.io/lessons/chrome-devtools-analyze-http-requests-and-responses-with-chrome-devtools